# Python 3.7 Tkinter frame reference ever increasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Apologies I'm pretty new at this...

I can't seem to 'overwrite' my tkinter frame. I've written this to demonstrate my problem:

```
from tkinter import *

bgCol = 'red'

def destroyMasterFrame():
    global master
    master.destroy()
    createMasterFrame()

def createMasterFrame():
    global master, bgCol

    if bgCol == 'green':
        bgCol = 'red'
    else:
        bgCol='green'

    master = Frame(root, bg=bgCol)
    master.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: destroyMasterFrame())
    master.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
    print(master)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+100+100')

createMasterFrame()

root.mainloop()
```

So every time I click the coloured square I thought I was destroying the frame and starting over, but `print(master)` gives me...

```
.!frame
.!frame2
.!frame3
.!frame4
.!frame5
```

...for each time I click. I know I'm probably missing something basic here but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

> Edit:

If I add an image to the frame that I'm destroying, it seems to keep it, along with the frame reference, in the memory which seems to fill the memory quickly with repeated use. This code demonstrates what I mean... How do I destroy the frame, its reference, and wipe everything contained within it from memory?...

```
from tkinter import *

def destroyMasterFrame():
    global master
    master.destroy()
    createMasterFrame()

def createMasterFrame():
    global master

    master = Frame(root, bg='green')
    master.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

    img = PhotoImage(file='test.png')
    label = Label(master, image=img)
    label.image = img
    label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: test())
    label.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')

    print(master)

def test():
    global myrange
    myrange = 1000
    for x in range(myrange):
        createMasterFrame()
        destroyMasterFrame()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+100+100')

createMasterFrame()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are realy deleting the frame:

```
def destroyMasterFrame():
    master.destroy()
    print(master)
```

If you check the frame is deleted.
The reference this stack is still alive.
Anyhow just the Frame is deletet but not the reference.
Therefor tkinter still counts up / even if the frame isnt behind.
So dont worry and keep going this way.
Hint: You dont need to user global twice.

> EDIT: (based on your comment)

Should work without clearing reference (no idea how to).
There should be a limit 2^63 <- max int in python.

Test case:

```
myrange = 100000
for x in range(myrange):
    createMasterFrame()
    destroyMasterFrame()
    if x == myrange-1:
        print(master)
```

Comment: Thank you that’s really helpful. So if I run the program and someone clicks this thousands of times then that’s still ok? Or do I need to clear the reference at some point? Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Thanks again Fabian for your help... However, I notice when I run this, the memory taken up by my program increases as it runs. If this is a long running program then how do I stop this from happening. In addition, this is only a simple frame with a background colour... if I add an image to the frame and run it again, even though I destroy the frame, the program memory increases massively as the program runs - like it's storing the image again and again without destroying it each time. I've edited the original question with a test script to demonstrate this. Thanks.

Comment: @gee702 the problem with your test case is that you "create" a second master frame in the "destroy" function but you only destroy the one created in your loop therefor you will stack atleast one each loop ^^ - it will work if you change this :)